# Webpack Running Debugger?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I refresh my route, `/questions` my component gets run by some kind of debugger I believe. See the `VM76464 Questions.jsx:105` line.
`componentDidMount()` gets run twice which is unexpected.

This only happens when I refresh the component, not when I am brought over to it by a link. Warning message also only appears when I refresh the component.

First time I am seeing this.

[image]

My `webpack.config.js` is...

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin') 

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
                use: 'babel-loader' 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: 'app/index.html'
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Questions.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getQuestions } from '../../utils/apiCalls'

import './question.css'

class Questions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            questions:[]
        }

        this.updateQuestions = this.updateQuestions.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('mount')
        this.updateQuestions()
    }

    async updateQuestions() {
        let questions = await getQuestions('http://localhost:1076/api/questions')
        this.setState({questions})
        console.log('update questions')
    }

    render() {
        const questions = this.state.questions
        console.log(questions)
        return ( 
            <div id='tinQuestions'>
                {
                    this.state.questions.length > 0 &&
                    <div id='tinQuestionsList'>
                        <h3>Discover</h3>
                        {
                            questions.map(question => {
                                return (
                                    <Link to={`question/${question.id}`} key={question.id}>
                                        {question.title}
                                    </Link>
                                )

                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Questions
```

Comment: Could you post `Questions.jsx` component?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning suggests,

```
async updateQuestions() {
        let questions = await getQuestions('http://localhost:1076/api/questions')
        this.setState({questions})
        console.log('update questions')
    }
```

gets called when `getQuestions` resolves and that could happen when the component is not mounted. It gets tricky. You will have to use cancelable wrapper promise. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html or use a subscription model for your apiCalls or introduce some kind of state manager that provides that.

Comment: But it only does that on a refresh, not when you navigate to /questions.
Why would that be different?

Comment: Something is causing `Questions` component to be mounted on refresh depending on how your rest of the code is structured or may be webpack hot reload if you are using that.